# Ubuntu 18.04 Server with windows10 on KVM Visualization

Tags: server, kernel, hard-drive, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 Server with windows10 on KVM Visualization. This is running on a Dell PowerEdge 2950 server.  I recently installed everything new, did all the updates and patches. 
I get the following error:

```
May 11 19:50:10 WIN-8JIJTG353IJ kernel: [ 6040.069658] sd 2:2:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
May 11 19:50:10 WIN-8JIJTG353IJ kernel: [ 6040.069677] sd 2:2:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 b3 78 08 00 00 08 00
May 11 19:50:10 WIN-8JIJTG353IJ kernel: [ 6040.069682] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 28538888
```

It only occurs when I start the `virsh` (Virtualization)

Any help will be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the exact command you entered? Perhaps also with a verbose flag? As far as I can see here, there is an issue with your guest disk.

Comment: I use the command  ' virsh start windows10' , I have the windows10.xml file which I can upload here if that will help.

Comment: Ok  - It was my raid sas drive that was split into two drives but one volume that was causing the issue. I have it on one drive and no errors for now